# Printing characters from string give different results

Tags: string, utf-8, d

I got confusing about UTF8 strings in D. Could someone explain why does this below code give different resuts? why does `"abç"[2] == 'ç'` is `false` and not `true`?

```
string s = "abç";
for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
{
    dchar c = s[i];
    writefln("%#x", cast(int)c);
}
writeln();
foreach(dchar c; s)
{
    writefln("%#x", cast(int)c);
}
```

This code output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ç` character has a UNICODE code-point greater than 7F (is E7) hence is represented inside an UTF8 string as more than one `char` (is the pair  C3 A7)

`s[2]` is just the 3rd `char` in `s` (and the first char of 'ç')

Your first loop prints the "bytes" as they are. (taken as s[i])
Yout second loop converts the code-points in s in UTF32.

e7 and C3 A7 are just the UTF32 and UTF8 encoding of the same (U+00E7) character.

For reference: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e7/index.htm

Comment: So if I want to get the second character from give string `s` with unicode characters,  `s[1]` will not work? should I deal with code-point to do it?

Comment: Yes: codepoints in UTF8 are not all the same length, so a direct index is useless (unless you can prior prove all the string is ASCII).

Comment: I know they aren't all the same length but didn't realized it isn't going to work in D. What's the D way to get a character by index?

Comment: In UTF8 it makes no sense. In whatever language. If you want to work by directly indexing characters you have to use UTF32 strings. At least until UNICODE codepoints will remain less than 2^^32

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't know much about UTF-8 as I should do.

Comment: @jack you can convert to dstring (where you can index properly) with std.utf.toUTF32();

Comment: take a look at this too http://dlang.org/phobos/std_uni.html#normalize some characters have several different representations in Unicode. That function tries to normalize it. Unicode strings are crazy complex though.